# Use a foreach loop to access the array within this queryresult object?

Tags: php, foreach

A print_r of my object ($results) returns the following:

```
QueryResult Object 
( [queryLocator] => [done] => 1 [records] => 
Array ( [0] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0167 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => MM Sample Organization-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FwjjEAC ) [Id] => a0V80000003FwjjEAC ) 
[1] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0170 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => Kansas City, Missouri Public Schools-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003Fxf9EAC ) [Id] => a0V80000003Fxf9EAC ) 
[2] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0169 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => Newark Public Schools-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FxQ2EAK ) [Id] => a0V80000003FxQ2EAK ) 
[3] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0168 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => Breakthrough Charter Schools-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FxPxEAK ) [Id] => a0V80000003FxPxEAK ) 
[4] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0004 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => KIPP, San Antonio-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FrBUEA0 ) [Id] => a0V80000003FrBUEA0 ) 
[5] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0003 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => KIPP, Chicago - Gary-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FrB5EAK ) [Id] => a0V80000003FrB5EAK )  
[6] => SObject Object ( [type] => Partner_Research__c [fields] => stdClass Object ( [Partner_Research_URL__c] => http://www.forms.com/184320?tfa_PRID=PR-0023 [Partner_Research_Name__c] => Harlem Village Academies-TBR Partner 2011 [Id] => a0V80000003FrEOEA0 ) [Id] => a0V80000003FrEOEA0 ) ) [size] => 7 )
```

I want to use a loop similar to the what is shown below to display a series of results however the foreach statement is incorrect.

```
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
    $id = $result[fields][Id];
    $name = $result[fields][Partner_Research_Name__c];
    $url = $result[fields][Partner_Research_URL__c];

    $html .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$url</td></tr>";
  }
```

What changes do I need to make to the foreach statement to get my code back on track?

Comment: What's the class definition of `QueryResult`?  Is it from a framework (which one), or did you write it yourself?

Comment: `Object` means it's an object, not an array.

Comment: @Ignacio: But if it implements `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate` it can be treated like an array, so it might work just like that (well the foreach bit anyway)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$results` is the name of the QueryResults object, I don't know what the real name in your code is.

```
foreach ($results->records as $result)
{
  $id = $result->Id;
  $name = $result->fields->Partner_Research_Name__c;
  $url = $result->fields->Partner_Research_URL__c;

  $html .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$url</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: (1) The variable's called `$results` in the original code (see the first words of the question).  (2) Where's `$results->results` (or `$ResultObject->results`, if you insist) coming from? ie: Explain how/why this is correct?

Answer (score 2):

What helps me in problems like this is to try to print inside the foreach loop.  For example, you can do a var_dump of each $result and see what that structure is, and it could help determine how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I eventually did it, thanks for the help provided by contributors.

```
  foreach ($results->records as $result)
  { 
    $id = $result->fields->Id;
    $name = $result->fields->Partner_Research_Name__c;
    $url = $result->fields->Partner_Research_URL__c;

    $html .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$url</td></tr>";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your sample correctly, your items are std objects instead of arrays. You may need to reference them like this:

```
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
    $id = $result->fields->Id;
    $name = $result->fields->Partner_Research_Name__c;
    $url = $result->fields->Partner_Research_URL__c;

    $html .= "<tr><td>$id</td><td>$name</td><td>$url</td></tr>";
  }
```

Your print_r sample above is difficult to read. If you could provide it with the indentation it would be helpful.

Comment: I added the indentation to the question